# Unit Test -> Could not find the correct Provider<Counter> above this ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter> Widget

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, flutter-test

I want to create a unit test for the Provider (`ChangeNotifierProvider`) in my project, my unit test, widget test and integration tests passed successfully ✔️, so now I tried (tried hard ...) to create a unit test to the provider. I was able to check the context, but when checking the initial value of the provider (must be 0), I get this exception ❌:

```sh
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundError was thrown running a test:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Counter> above this ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>
Widget

To fix, please:

  * Ensure the Provider<Counter> is an ancestor to this ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter> Widget
  * Provide types to Provider<Counter>
  * Provide types to Consumer<Counter>
  * Provide types to Provider.of<Counter>()
  * Always use package imports. Ex: `import 'package:my_app/my_code.dart';
  * Ensure the correct `context` is being used.

If none of these solutions work, please file a bug at:
https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:264:7)
#1      main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///home/chinnonsantos/FlutterProjects/full_testing_flutter/test/unit/provider_test.dart:33:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:119:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:648:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:631:14)
#7      AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1016:24)
#13     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1013:15)
#14     testWidgets.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:116:22)
#15     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:168:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:250:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#21     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:247:5)
#22     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:166:33)
#27     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:165:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#28     Invoker._onRun.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:400:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#42     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
#43     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
#44     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
(elided 28 frames from class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, package dart:async-patch, and package stack_trace)

The test description was:
  Update when the value changes
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
00:03 +0 -1: [Provider] Update when the value changes [E]                                                               
  Test failed. See exception logs above.
  The test description was: Update when the value changes

00:03 +0 -1: Some tests failed.                                                                                         
Collecting coverage information...
```

Follow my code:
- `pubspec.yaml`:

```
...
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  test: ^1.6.3
  provider: ^3.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  pedantic: ^1.8.0+1
...
```

- `lib/main.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:full_testing_flutter/counter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => Counter(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Consumer<Counter>(
              builder: (context, counter, child) => Text(
                '${counter.value}',
                key: Key('counter'),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        key: Key('increment'),
        onPressed: () =>
            Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false).increment(),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- `lib/counter.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int value = 0;

  void increment() {
    value++;
    // print('Value++: $value');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void decrement() {
    value--;
    // print('Value--: $value');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

- `test/unit/provider_test.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:full_testing_flutter/main.dart';
import 'package:full_testing_flutter/counter.dart';

void main() async {
  Counter _counterModel;

  setUp(() {
    _counterModel = Counter();
  });

  group('[Provider]', () {
    testWidgets('Update when the value changes', (tester) async {
      final _providerKey = GlobalKey();
      BuildContext context;

      await tester.pumpWidget(ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>(
        key: _providerKey,
        create: (c) {
          context = c;
          return Counter();
        },
        child: MyApp(),
      ));

      // Check the context test...
      expect(context, equals(_providerKey.currentContext));

      // Check the initial value provider 0...
      expect(Provider.of<Counter>(_providerKey.currentContext).value, 0);

      // // Increment value...
      // Provider.of<Counter>(_providerKey.currentContext).increment();

      // // Delay the pump...
      // await Future.microtask(tester.pump);

      // // Check if incremented value is the same as received...
      // expect(
      //   Consumer<Counter>(
      //     builder: (context, counter, child) => Text('${counter.value}'),
      //   ),
      //   _counterModel.value,
      // );

      // // Decrement value...
      // Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false).decrement();

      // // Delay the pump...
      // await Future.microtask(tester.pump);

      // // Check if decremented value is the same as received...
      // expect(
      //   Provider.of<Counter>(_childKey.currentContext).value,
      //   _counterModel.value,
      // );
    });
  });
}
```

- `test/unit/counter_test.dart`, `test/widget/widget_test.dart` and `test_driver/app_test.dart`:

  > It's not important right now, but if you want to see it, it's available in the [full_testing_flutter (public project)](https://github.com/chinnonsantos/full_testing_flutter) repository

**What I can do to test the Provider (isolated)? Where is the error in my code?**

I'm starting with Dart/Flutter and especially the Provider package, can anyone help me?

*Note: My app works perfectly, only my unit test for the provider (what I'm implementing now) doesn't work !!!*

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem happens because you are using the `BuildContext` of the provider you want to obtain to call `Provider.of`:

```dart
Provider<T>(
  key: myKey,
  ...
)


Provider.of<T>(myKey.currentContext);
```

This is not possible, and only the descendants of the said provider can call `Provider.of`.

Consider changing your test to something like:

```dart
testWidget('Provider.of', (tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(
    Provider(
      create: (_) => 42,
      child: Container(),
    ),
  );

  final context = tester.element(find.byType(Container));

  expect(Provider.of<int>(context), equals(42));
});
```

Comment: Very very good!!! Now it works perfectly... Thank you very much 
I used my own **`MyApp`** widget with my model class **`Counter`**, so it looked like this:

`final BuildContext childContext = tester.element(find.byType(MyApp));` and `expect(Provider.of<Counter>(childContext).value, 0);`